# Preparing a custom made download

Tags: php, javascript, download, drupal-7

I would like to create a form that will allow for custom download assembling, just like the one on [jQuery UI download page](http://jqueryui.com/download). The user selects the components s/he needs and a custom download is assembled, (g)zipped and sent out. How does this work? How do I write something similar?

Optionally: since I'd like to implement this on a Drupal 7 site, suggestions for helpful modules are also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jnpcl's answer works. However, if you want to download the file without requiring a redirect, just do the following:

```
// Once you created your zip file as say $zipFile, you can output it directly
// like the following
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($zipFile));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipFile));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($zipFile);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: Thank you, I believe this is just what I was looking for in order to send the file over. I've heard something about sending appropriate headers earlier, but I've never actually done this before :).

Answer (score 2):

Simple implementation:

```
<?php
    // base directory containing files that we're adding
    $dir = 'images/';

    // name of our zip file. best to use a unique name here
    $zipfile = "test.zip";

    // get a directory listing, remove self/parent directories, and reindex array
    $files = array_values(array_diff(scandir($dir), array('.', '..')));

    // form has been submitted
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        // initialize the zip file
        $output = new ZipArchive();
        $output->open($zipfile, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
        // add files to archive
        foreach ($_POST['file'] as $num=>$file) {
            // make sure the files are valid
            if (is_file($dir . $file) && is_readable($dir . $file)) {
                // add it to our zip file
                $output->addFile($dir . $file);
            }
        }
        // write zip file to filesystem
        $output->close();
        // direct user's browser to the zip file
        header("Location: " . $zipfile);
        exit();
    } else {
        // display filenames with checkboxes
        echo '<form method="POST">' . PHP_EOL;
        for ($x=0; $x<count($files); $x++) {
            echo '  <input type="checkbox" name="file[' . $x . ']" value="' . $files[$x] . '">' . $files[$x] . '<br>' . PHP_EOL;
        }
        echo '  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '</form>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
?>
```

Known bug: Doesn't check if `$zipfile` exists beforehand. If it does, it will be appended to.

Answer (score 1):

i dont know anything about that drupal but probably is some help editor for php or similar... however this may help you... [PHP ZIP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php)

never used it but it dont seams hard!

hope it helps

Comment: +1, although this only covers the most obvious part, one that I could figure out myself. What bugs me is how I make the form submit button download the zipped bundle.

Comment: you make form wich submits checkbox values to php file and in php you check if checkbox 1 for file 1 was checked if it was then add it to zip... and then for checkbox 2 and so on and once it comes to end you close zip file and make it to some folder and just redirect user to that file header("location: newfiles/thatfileyoumade.zip");
something like that... helps?